# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object issue in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i new to Unity3D, so i take look to tutorials, and bump into issue with error linked in tittle of this thread. So. i Wrote exactly code that this guy wrote, and do also exactly what he do, but get error. I add rigidbody to mine player object. Here picture:
[image]

Tutorial: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/set-up?playlist=17141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the `setup()` function is ever called, which initializes the `rb` variable? It seems like this is variable, which is `null`. Try to replace `rb.AddForce(mouvment * speed)` with `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(mouvement * speed);`. Alternatively, rename your `setup()` function to `Awake()` or `Start()`.

Comment: I don't know why, i didin't check that thing, maybe because it is in "routin that repeat always"